# How to format data purge email report

Tags: sql-server, format, report, html-email, purge

I need to send an emailed monthly report which has the results of a data purge and in that report I need to have the 2 columns below.

1. Table name
2. Number of records deleted

Emailed report needs to look like:

```
TableName | Deleted Records
---------------------------
dbo.table1  | 4287
dbo.table2  | 90276
dbo.table3  | 382
```

Below is a an example of my delete statements. I have put them in a stored proc.

```
      Delete from dbo.table1 where date = 'value'
      SELECT 'dbo.table1' as Tablename , @@ROWCOUNT AS 'Record_Count'
      Delete from dbo.table2 where date = 'value'
      SELECT 'dbo.table2' as Tablename , @@ROWCOUNT AS 'Record_Count'
      Delete from dbo.table3 where date = 'value'
      SELECT 'dbo.table3' as Tablename , @@ROWCOUNT AS 'Record_Count'
```

When I run the following to send the report, the emailed format isn't clean.

```
      EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @profile_name = 'SQL DBA',  
      @recipients = 'myemail.com',  
      @body = 'Please see the report below for this months Data Purge',
      @body_format = TEXT,
      @query = 'EXECUTE datapurge SP',
      @execute_query_database = 'databasenamegoeshere',
      @subject = 'Data purge record count',
      @query_result_header = 1,
      @query_result_width = 256,
      @query_result_separator = ',',
      @query_result_no_padding = 1;
```

```
    Actual emailed results:

dbo.table1,10641
Tablename,Record_Count
---------,------------
dbo.table2,112141
Tablename,Record_Count




But it needs to look like:

TableName   | Deleted Records
---------------------------
dbo.table1  | 10641
dbo.table2  | 112141
dbo.table3  | 382
```

or

```
TableName   | Deleted Records
----------------------------
dbo.table1  | 10641
----------------------------
dbo.table2  | 112141
----------------------------
dbo.table3  | 382
```

Comment: Save the results of your deletes into a table and select them after deletes are performed so you get everything in one resultset

Comment: CCONVERT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @siggemannen I have thought about that as well but I'm not able to successfully do so. Are you thinking of getting a row count of the delete statement first, inserting it into a table, and then running the delete statements?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean I'm not sure what you mean by using the convert statement. I just want to email a report that looks readable.

Comment: Can you send the text body as HTML instead? If you can, it can be put into a table. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6914/beautify-html-tables-email-sql-database-mail/

Answer (score 0):

Answering here instead.
You can change your procedure to something like:

```sql
create procedure datapurge
as
begin
      create table #results (tablename sysname, cnt INT)

      Delete from dbo.table1 where date = 'value'
      insert into #results
      SELECT 'dbo.table1' as Tablename , @@ROWCOUNT AS 'Record_Count'
      Delete from dbo.table2 where date = 'value'
      insert into #results
      SELECT 'dbo.table2' as Tablename , @@ROWCOUNT AS 'Record_Count'
      Delete from dbo.table3 where date = 'value'
      insert into #results
      SELECT 'dbo.table3' as Tablename , @@ROWCOUNT AS 'Record_Count'
      select *
      FROM #results
      ORDER BY 1
end
```

This way, the output will be a bit nicer